# Make an array out of JSON response

Tags: ios, arrays, alamofire, swifty-json

I have following response to get Areas but I need an Individual array out of this with separator

```
 {
        "name" : "Abu Hail",
        "city_id" : 1,
        "pk" : 227,
        "city" : "Dubai"
      },
      {
        "name" : "Academic City",
        "city_id" : 1,
        "pk" : 184,
        "city" : "Dubai"
      },
      {
        "name" : "Al Barari",
        "city_id" : 1,
        "pk" : 185,
        "city" : "Dubai"
      },
      {
        "name" : "Al Barsha 1,2 & 3",
        "city_id" : 1,
        "pk" : 166,
        "city" : "Dubai"
      },
```

How can I make an array from name below out of this

```
 ["Abu Hail", "Academic City", "Al Barari", "Al Barsha 1,2 & 3"]
```

Following are my codes to get the above response

```
func getAreas(){
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Token \(token!)",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
        AF.request("\(staging.url)/api/addresses/areas/", method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch response.result {

            case let .success(value):

                let json = JSON(value)
                print("Areas Array: \(json)")
```

Comment: you could write `array.compactMap { $0["name" } as? [String]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create array using:

```
if let array = array as? [[String : Any]] {
   let namesArray = array.compactMap { $0["name"] } as? [String]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to create codable objects

```
// MARK: - AreaElement
struct AreaElement: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let cityID, pk: Int?
    let city: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case cityID = "city_id"
        case pk, city
    }
}
```

Now you can directly parse using `JSONDecoder` like

```
 fileprivate func retrieve<T: Decodable>(data: Data, type: T.Type) -> T? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let model = try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
            return model
        } catch(let error) {
            return nil
        }
   }


    AF.request("\(staging.url)/api/addresses/areas/", method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers).responseData { (response:DataResponse<Data>) in


  if let data =  response.data {
      let models = self.retrieve(data: data, type: [Area].self)

       // How you get name from model  with one line 
       let names = models?.map {$0.name} 
    }

       .......
```

Hopefully it will be helpful